# Extracting arguments from IDA

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython, python

Let's say I have the following function in IDA:

```
int __usercall function<eax>(char* message<ebp>, unsigned int count<edi>)
```

What's the fastest way to extract the argument information using IDAPython, such that I get the following:

```
[['char*', 'message', 'ebp'],['unsigned int','count','edi']]
```

Not that it also needs to handle situations like:

```
void *__usercall sub_4508B0@<rax>(void *(__usercall *function)@<rax>(int one@<eax>)@<rax>);
```

Which should give me something along the lines of:

```
[['void * ...', 'function', 'rax']]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I received an answer from HexRays support which has a solution which does not rely on parsing the C string retrieved by `GetType(ea)`.

Let's imagine we start with a function prototype:

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
```

That's from an ELF file, x86 abi; stuff is passed on the stack.

Then, I can do the following:

```
Python>from idaapi import *
Python>tif = tinfo_t()
Python>get_tinfo2(here(), tif)
True
Python>funcdata = func_type_data_t()
Python>tif.get_func_details(funcdata)
True
Python>funcdata.size()
3
Python>for i in xrange(funcdata.size()):
Python>    print "Arg %d: %s (of type %s, and of location: %s)" % (i, funcdata[i].name, print_tinfo('', 0, 0, PRTYPE_1LINE, funcdata[i].type, '', ''), funcdata[i].argloc.atype())
Python>
Arg 0: argc (of type int, and of location: 1)
Arg 1: argv (of type const char **, and of location: 1)
Arg 2: envp (of type const char **, and of location: 1)
```

Note that it tells me the location type is `1`, which corresponds
to 'stack':
https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/group___a_l_o_c__.html

Now, let's assume I change the prototype to this:

```
.text:0804ABA1 ; int __usercall main@<eip>(int argc@<eax>, const char **argv@<esp>, const char **envp@<edx>)
```

Then:

```
Python>get_tinfo2(here(), tif)
True
Python>tif.get_func_details(funcdata)
True
Python>for i in xrange(funcdata.size()):
Python>    print "Arg %d: %s (of type %s, and of location: %s)" % (i, funcdata[i].name, print_tinfo('', 0, 0, PRTYPE_1LINE, funcdata[i].type, '', ''), funcdata[i].argloc.atype())
Python>
Arg 0: argc (of type int, and of location: 3)
Arg 1: argv (of type const char **, and of location: 3)
Arg 2: envp (of type const char **, and of location: 3)
```

Argument location type is `3` now, which corresponds to 'inside
register'.

(Then, I would have to use `reg1()` to retrieve the actual
register number to know *what* register the argument is
passed in)

Credit goes to Arnaud of Hex Rays.