# Where Ida Pro is using my defined structures

Tags: ida, disassembly, struct

I'm have many functions that has a structure pointer as a function parameter (e.g. "VecInt *"). Ida knows that each function uses this type (because decompile window works fine). The same will happen if this function uses this type in a local variable.

Now I would like to see all functions that are using this particular structure (as parameter or local variable). I believe Ida maintains this information ("functions where this structure is used") as internal data.

Is possible to extract or have access to this data?.

The structures window don't show this information as "XREF: etc etc", even when I increase cross reference depth.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Cross references to structures are only available when used directly in the disassembly view. For retrieving them when used exclusively in the pseudo-code or in the function's prototype, I'm afraid you have no other chance but walking the functions (for function in Functions()), getting the prototype (GetType(function)) and parsing it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a specific IDA API (discussed recently [here] (http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/extracting-arguments-from-ida) to avoid parsing the GetType() result.