# IDA: Extracting functions arguments from stripped binary

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython

[This thread](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/extracting-arguments-from-ida/8876#8876) describes method for extracting function arguments from ida. However this method is not working for stripped binaries (funcdata.size() is always 0).
Is it possible to extract such information from stripped binaries?

Comment: The thread to which you linked is relying on analyses from the [Hex-Rays Decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml), not on embedded symbols. Do you have the Hex-Rays Decompiler installed?

Comment: Yes, i have hex-rays decompiler and it works fine with recovring function prototype from stripped file.
But the script from thread does not work for stripped binaries.

Comment: When you press the `Y` key on the function, what is its prototype string? And where does the script from the other thread fail?

Comment: It seems that the problem was with my decompiler on ubuntu. I could get the script work on windows. 
Thank you very much for help.