# How to list parameter of function from IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, assembly, idapython, functions

I want to list parameter of function for analysis. Can I list the parameter of function using IDA Pro or IDAPython ?

Comment: The answer to this question is covered here: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/extracting-arguments-from-ida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with some hack like this ?

```
cmt = GetType(ScreenEA());
print cmt
fc = cmt.split("(")
sc = fc[1].split(")")
tc = sc[0].split(",")
for s in tc:
    print s
```

result when cursor is in functionstart

```
int __stdcall(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
HINSTANCE hInstance
 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance
 LPSTR lpCmdLine
 int nShowCmd
```

Comment: What if the function accepts callbacks as parameters? e.g `int __cdecl sub_401000(int (*a1)(int), char a2)`

Comment: well if world falls tomorrow because we are hacking we fall with it and hack underworld or if we are unlucky get to over-world and hack there any way ws posted a comment to the original question where it appears there is a better method to get the function arguments take a look at the link posted by ws to original qestion