# IDA: Changing type of arguments to local type

Tags: ida, idapython

I have functions

```
foo_0(...,_ v0,...)
foo_1(...,_ v1,...)
...
```

And, for each `(foo_x, _ v_x)` pair, I would like to change the type of `v_x` in the declaration to `ANIMAL *`, where `ANIMAL` is a local type.

I recycled some code from [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/), as follow:

```
from idaapi import *

tif = tinfo_t()
get_tinfo2(ea, tif)

funcdata = func_type_data_t()
tif.get_func_details(funcdata)
```

After this I was stuck, as `funcdata[i].type` is a `tinfo_t` object which I could not find a way to create/modify easily.

My last resort would be to use `GuessType`/`GetType` and modify the string before `SetType`, but this might be a tad complicated since some arguments are pointers to functions themselves.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me (checks might be needed on `guess_tinfo` and `get_func_details`)

```
tif = idaapi.tinfo_t()
ida_typeinf.guess_tinfo(ea,tif)                     
funcdata = idaapi.func_type_data_t()
tif.get_func_details(funcdata)
tif2 = idaapi.tinfo_t()
tif2.get_named_type(idaapi.get_idati(),"ANIMAL")       #tif2 = ANIMAL
tif3 = tinfo_t()
tif3.create_ptr(tif2)                                  #tif3 = ANIMAL *
funcdata[argnum].type = tif3                           #replace corresponding argument
function_tinfo = idaapi.tinfo_t()
function_tinfo.create_func(funcdata)
idaapi.apply_tinfo2(ea, function_tinfo, idaapi.TINFO_DEFINITE)
```

Comment: For IDA SDK >= 7.4, the parameter order of the `guess_tinfo` is switched. It should be `guess_tinfo(tif,ea)`.